# C linked list - inserting node at the end

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to read from a list that has 1 word per line and 20 lines, and then add each word to the end of a linked list. My problem is that when I print out the linked list at the end it is printing that last word in the file 20 times instead of each word once. I have been working on this for hours and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

In my main I have

```
while (!feof(input)) {
        fscanf(input, "%s", currentName);
        head = insert(head, currentName);
}
print(head);
delete(head);
```

**Insert Function**

```
node* insert(node* head, char* name) {
        node *temp = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
                head = create_node(name);
        }
        else {
                temp = head;
                while(temp->next != NULL){
                        temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp->next = create_node(name);
            }
        return head;
}
```

**Create Function**

```
node* create_node(char* name) {
        node *newNode;
        newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(newNode == NULL) {
                printf("Failed to create node");
        }
        newNode->name = name;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return newNode;
}
```

**Print and Delete**

```
void print(node* head){
        while (head != NULL) {
                printf("%s -> ", head->name);
                head = head->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
}
void delete(node* head) {
        node *temp = NULL;
        while(head != NULL) {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp);
        }
}
```

Comment: what did the debugger say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the address of the same buffer back in `main()` for each and every insertion. Each node is simply holding the base address of `currentName`, the content of which is changed with each input processed. Therefore you have a linked list of structures containing `name` pointers, where each points to *the same buffer* (`currentName`). Thus the last one will be the only one you see.

You need to dynamically allocate space for the name in `create_node`. The following uses the POSIX function `strdup()` to do this, though you're perfectly free to use a `strlen/malloc` combination if you desire.

```
node* create_node(char* name) 
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(newNode == NULL)
        printf("Failed to create node");

    newNode->name = strdup(name);
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

Don't forget when you're cleanup up your linked list to `free()` each node name to avoid a memory leak.

```
void delete(node* head) 
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    while(head != NULL) 
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp->name);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Unrelated: Your while-loop condition for loading your content is wrong. [Read this answer to see why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong/5432517#5432517)